# Is the time-dependent matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the follow time-dependent matrix: 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}(t) = f(t)\mathbf{A}, \quad t\in [0,\infty),
\end{equation}
where $f(t)$ is a real-valued function such that $f(t) \neq 0\,$ for all $\, t $ into the defined interval, and $\mathbf{A}$ is an invertible square matrix.

Is the matrix $\mathbf{B}(t)$ invertible?

Comment: Yes, with inverse $f(t)^{-1}\mathbf A^{-1}$

Answer (score 3):

The inverse of $f(t)A$ is $(1/f(t))A^{-1}$.  The only trouble you might have would be when $f(t)=0$.  Another way of thinking about this problem is that multiplying the columns of a matrix by the same constant will not change its column space.  So if it was invertible to begin with, it stays invertible.

Comment: Symbolically, I have no doubts about what you answered. But I am not safe about the form of $f(t)$ and the interval of $t$. Because if we suppose that $f(t)=e^t$, for $t \geq 0$ these exponencial functions lie in a semigroup structure (which has no inverse element). In sense of this, I am thinking about $\mathbf{B}(t)$ having a semigroup structure, and consequently, it is not invertible. I am thankful for the answer.

Comment: @Clus, I am somewhat confused by your comment.  $G$ is a semi-group if its is closed under an operation and if that operation is associate.  The set of functions $f(t)=ce^{gt}$ with the operation multiplication is in fact a group.  It has an identity element, the constant function $f(t)=1$ .  Every element has an inverse:  $f^{-1}=(1/c)e^{-gt}$, and the set of functions is closed is closed under function multiplication since $f_1*f_2=c_1c_2e^{(g_1+g_2)t}$.   My answer used this inverse $1/f(t)=(1/c)e^{-gt}$

Comment: I got your explanation. But when you defined $G$ as a semigroup if its is closed under an operation and if that operation is associate, the existence of inverses and identity is not required. I agree with you about the group structure that you show.  I have no certainty what I am thinking about. I apologize upfront my lack of clarity.

Comment: In fact, the set of functions $f(t)=ce^{gt}$ is a group, with the inverse $1/f(t)=(1/c)e^{-gt}$. However, if we consider only $ t \geq 0 $ not all the group axioms are satisfied. For simplicity,  consider $c=g=1$. In this case, closure $f(t) \cdot f(t^{\prime}) = e^{t} \cdot e^{t^{\prime}} = e^{t^{\prime \prime}}=f(t^{\prime \prime})$ with $t^{\prime \prime} = t + t^{\prime}$  where $t, t^{\prime},t^{\prime \prime} \geq 0$. The multiplication is clearly associative.

Comment: The identity element is found if exist an element on the set of  $e^{t}$ with $t \geq 0$ such that $e^{t}e^{t^{\prime}}=e^{t}$, what is satisfied by $t^{\prime}=0$, thus, the identity element is given by $e^{0}=1$. My question consists in the inverse element in this case. Because, for it exists, we need to find an element into the set of the functions $e^{t}$  with $t \geq 0$ such that satisfies $e^{t}e^{t^{\prime}}=1$, and it will be satisfied only if $t^{\prime}=-t$, and $t^{\prime} \leq 0$, which implies in inverse element  $e^{-t}$ that is not in the set.

Comment: @Cius You are messing up with different notations that are not accounting for the same thing. $G\subset\mathbb R$ being a semigroup or not has nothing to do with whether its element, which belongs to $\mathbb R$, is invertible in $\mathbb R$.